# How do I create a LayerDrawable vertically oriented

Tags: android, drawable

I want to create a LayerDrawable with the top drawable a text, and the buttom drawable a drawable from the resources. How can I achieve this programmatically?

I need a compound floating action button with text and image but the FAB is not a view group so I couldn't do that. Using a LayerDrawable seems to be the alternative.

Comment: `with the top drawable a text,` there is no such thing like "TextDrawable": you would either create a custom `Drawable` class or use "compound bottom drawable" in your FAB

Comment: @pskink Thanks, I know that already. I've created both drawables but how do I align them, on on top of the other. With xml, this can be done but how do I do it programmatically?

Comment: so how did you do that in xml? and if you did it, so why cant you use xml solution?

Comment: @pskink with a layer-list. I can't use xml solution because text is dynamic and I can't exaclty create a drawable with text in xml.

Comment: **LayerDrawable**: `It can be defined in an XML file with the <layer-list> element. Each Drawable in the layer is defined in a nested <item>.` but honestly the easier aproach is to create a custom `Drawable` class

Comment: @pskink That is the question, a custom  drawable with a layerlist

Comment: so you need probably `setLayerInsetTop(int,int) Top inset to apply to the layer. ` (as i see its v23 API, no good) but if it doesn't work use a custom `Drawable` and override its `draw` method

Comment: @pskink well, you're a bomb ser! Thanks!

Comment: `"bomb ser!"` ??? what is das?

Comment: @pskink you're awesome!

Comment: ok if you dont want to implement all `Drawable` class methods you can use a custom `Shape` and pass it to `ShapeDrawable` constructor